# Retrieve selective data in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I created a mongoDB collection using php:-

```
$document = array(
         'id' => 5,
         'UNAME' => 'abc',
         'NAME' => 'def',
         'EMAIL' => 'def@gmail.com',
         'QUALIFICATION' => array(
                     'DEGREE' => '',
                     'UNIVERSITY' => ''
                    ),
         'POST' => array(
             ),
        );
$collection->insert($document);
```

I have this mongodb collection:-

```
{
"_id" : "5",
"UNAME" : "abc",
"NAME" : "def",
"EMAIL" : "def@gmail.com",
"QUALIFICATION" : {
    "DEGREE" : "",
    "UNIVERSITY" : ""
},
"POST" : [ ]
}
{
"_id" : "2",
"UNAME" : "uvw",
"NAME" : "xyz",
"EMAIL" : "xyz@gmail.com",
"QUALIFICATION" : {
    "DEGREE" : "",
    "UNIVERSITY" : ""
},
"POST" : [ ]
}
```

I used the query as `$cursor = $collection->find(array('UNAME'=>'uvw'));`

```
$extract = iterator_to_array($cursor);
```

Now the problem lies here.
To retrieve the document with UNAME = uvw I'm forced to use

```
$u = $extract[2]['UNAME'];
```

And instead if I use `$u = $extract['UNAME'];`
it show me error as,`Notice: Undefined index: UNAME`

Is there a way I can get this data without using 'index'(I guess this is the right word)?

Comment: `$u = $extract[2]['UNAME'];` are you sure this will work? i don't think so. Looking the format i think `$u = $extract->UNAME;` is the correct way to get the data

Comment: @A-2-A Using `$u = $extract->UNAME;` gives error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Can you show what `$extract` have by printing this?

Comment: @A-2-A `$extract` gives `Array ( [2] => Array ( [_id] => 2 [UNAME] => uvw [NAME] => xyz [EMAIL] => xyz@gmail.com [QUALIFICATION] => Array ( [DEGREE] => [UNIVERSITY] => ) [POST] => Array ( ) ) ) 1`

Comment: then you need to do in that way only or you can do some work and get a new array and then only directly uname will be accesible

Comment: `$extract = $extract[2];` and then you can do `$extract['UNAME']`

Comment: @A-2A by getting new array you mean working on the content of `$extract` to get an array in better format? right?

Comment: @A-2A But this won't resolve the problem if I am having nested arrays in this document. Every nested array will face the same problem.

Comment: yes,actually i am confused that how the above data give you index 2 when you converted it to array, because its` json` i think and converting it into array will not give index 2. May be i am not correct , but yes i mean the same `by getting new array you mean working on the content of $extract to get an array in better format? right?`

Comment: @A-2A This is the query i used to insert data into the collection `db.a.insert({ "_id" : "5", "UNAME" : "abc", "NAME" : "def", "EMAIL" : "def@gmail.com", "QUALIFICATION":{"DEGREE" : "","UNIVERSITY" : "" }, "POST" : [ ] })`. Is this the root of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since your query is `find(array('UNAME'=>'uvw'))` why do you have to search for `UNAME` in response? Isn't it obvious that in all the responses value of `UNAME` will be `uvw`?

Second thing is [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) will return the array containing all the documents in an array, where key of each document will be the value of _id.
So in your case response will be

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 2
            [UNAME] => uvw
            [NAME] => xyz
            [EMAIL] => xyz@gmail.com
            [QUALIFICATION] => Array
                (
                    [DEGREE] => 
                    [UNIVERSITY] => 
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

And because of that, you have to find `UNAME` using `$extract[2]['UNAME'];`

However you can change this behavior by passing value `use_keys` to FALSE, where `use_keys` indicates whether the iterator element keys are to be used as index or not.

So, `$extract = iterator_to_array($cursor, FALSE)`

Will return array with index starting from 0 as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 2
            [UNAME] => uvw
            [NAME] => xyz
            [EMAIL] => xyz@gmail.com
            [QUALIFICATION] => Array
                (
                    [DEGREE] => 
                    [UNIVERSITY] => 
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So, now you can find `UNAME` using `$extract[0]['UNAME'];`

Hope this helps.